# How to join list of ids with another table many to many in EFcore3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi everyone i have many to many relation between invoice and product and the join class is customer invoice i want to insert invoice and add many product to it.
one of the answer when i ask in other place told me you make list of product while your join class take only one product but if you make it list of product inside the customer invoice it will work and i make it still not work anyone can explain and how the code should be
this is the function.

```
 try
            {

                Invoice invoice = new Invoice
                {
                    InvoiceNote = addCustomerInvoice.InvoiceNote,
                    AdminId = addCustomerInvoice.AdminId,
                    CustomerId = addCustomerInvoice.CustomerId,
                    CompanyStoresId = addCustomerInvoice.CompanyStoresId,
                    InvoiceDate = addCustomerInvoice.InvoiceDate.Date,
                    
                };
                
                List<int>result= await _drugDbContext.Products.Select(p => p.ProductId).ToListAsync();
                


                CustomerInvoice customerInvoice = new CustomerInvoice
                {
                    Products =result,
                    Invoice = invoice
                    
                };
                await _drugDbContext.CustomerInvoices.AddAsync(customerInvoice);
                await _drugDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                servicesResponse.Data = _mapper.Map<InvoiceForGet>(invoice);
            }
```

```
public class Invoice
    {
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset InvoiceDate { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        public string InvoiceNote { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public int AdminId { get; set; }
        public Admin Admin { get; set; }
        public int CompanyStoresId { get; set; }
        public CompanyStore CompanyStores { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CustomerInvoice> CustomerInvoices { get; set; }
         = new List<CustomerInvoice>();
        public ICollection<ProductsReturn> ProductsReturn { get; set; }
         = new List<ProductsReturn>();
    }
```

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public string BarCode { get; set; }
        public float BuyPrice { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductAndCategory> ProductCategory { get; set; }
= new List<ProductAndCategory>();
        public ICollection<TransportInvoice> transportInvoices { get; set; }
= new List<TransportInvoice>();
        public ICollection<CustomerInvoice> CustomerInvoices { get; set; }
       = new List<CustomerInvoice>();
        public ICollection<ProductsReturn> ProductsReturn { get; set; }
      = new List<ProductsReturn>();
        public int CompanyStoresId { get; set; }
        public CompanyStore CompanyStores { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OfficeInvoice> OfficeInvoices { get; set; }
   = new List<OfficeInvoice>();
        public ICollection<OfficeReturn> OfficeReturns { get; set; }
    = new List<OfficeReturn>();
    }
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInvoice>(entity =>
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInvoice>().HasKey(ci => new { ci.ProductId, ci.InvoiceId });
                entity.HasKey(c => c.CustomerInvoiceId);
                entity.Property(c => c.Quantity).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(c => c.TotalPrice).IsRequired();
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInvoice>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(c => c.Products)
                       .WithMany(p => p.CustomerInvoices)
                       .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId)
                       .IsRequired(false)
                       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInvoice>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(c => c.Invoice)
                       .WithMany(i => i.CustomerInvoices)
                       .HasForeignKey(c => c.InvoiceId)
                       .IsRequired(false)
                       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
            });
```

```
public class CustomerInvoice
    {
        public int CustomerInvoiceId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public float Discount { get; set; }
        public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Products { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductsReturn> ProductsReturn { get; set; }
       = new List<ProductsReturn>();
    }
```

```
this is the dto class
        public class AddCustomerInvoice
    {
        public ICollection<Product> products { get; set; }
         = new List<Product>();
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNote { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int AdminId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyStoresId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a one to many. E.g. 1 invoice have many products? What is the purpose of Invoice compared to customer invoice?

Comment: it's same order and item many to many. i just want to make the function take list of ids inside and join them

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft can you see this question for me?

Comment: @marc_s please can you answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple demo based on your codes and requirement for how to insert a record with many-to-many relationship.

Below is the code:

**Model:**

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNote { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerInvoice> CustomerInvoices { get; set; }
     = new List<CustomerInvoice>();
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerInvoice> CustomerInvoices { get; set; }
   = new List<CustomerInvoice>();
}

public class CustomerInvoice
{
    public int CustomerInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Products { get; set; }
}

public class AddCustomerInvoice
{
    public ICollection<Product> products { get; set; }
     = new List<Product>();
    public string InvoiceNote { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    AddCustomerInvoice addCustomerInvoice = new AddCustomerInvoice
    {
        products = new List<Product> 
        { 
            new Product { ProductId = 1, Price = 3, Quantity = 10},
            new Product { ProductId = 2, Price = 5, Quantity = 10},
            new Product { ProductId = 3, Price = 6, Quantity = 10},
            new Product { ProductId = 4, Price = 2, Quantity = 10},
        },

        InvoiceNote = "ddddd"
    };

    Invoice invoice = new Invoice
    {
        InvoiceNote = addCustomerInvoice.InvoiceNote,
    };

    _drugDbContext.Invoices.Add(invoice);
    _drugDbContext.SaveChanges();

    int invoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId;

    foreach (var item in addCustomerInvoice.products)
    {
        _drugDbContext.CustomerInvoices.Add(
        new CustomerInvoice 
        { 
            InvoiceId = invoiceId, 
            ProductId = item.ProductId,
            Quantity = item.Quantity,
            TotalPrice = item.Quantity * item.Price
        });
        _drugDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thank you soooo much for that but only have two things i'm make it in api  and the body will send all the addcustomerinvoice the body will make invoice  link it in one or more product.  and the second thing how to know about many to many in 3.1 i really search and read alot about it and ask many of dev they gave simple ex or the just gave the confg........ If you accept could you please give me any way i can communicate with you

Comment: The join table is used to connect invoices and products by the foreignkey(InvoiceId and ProductId), so you need to get the InvoicdeId and the corresponding productId then store them into the join table. if one Invoice links to many products, for example 1(InvoiceId)-1,2,3(ProductId), you need to divide it into 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, then store these three records in the join table, like the codes above, I use the foreach loop.

Comment: you mean first insert the invoice and then  return the ids from the database and make the join like the the loop you make to same id for many product(but how to return the many product as you can see above i try to make list of <int> inside is select of productId is that right for it and then i will make the loop you made to only join them?)

Comment: Could you please show me the function if i want to return list of prdocut that already in my database do i need to make the dto class take list product of list of int and make like this(`List<product> theList = _drugDbContext.Products.Where(c => c.productId == AddCustomerInvoice.productid).ToList();`) or how? i can't figure it out in api and take the info from body(dto)

Comment: I am not sure where the productIds come from, it is usually from the frontend. you can search product with these ids and add them to products list in the dto class.